# Pytorch - select region of a tensor using torch function

Tags: python, pytorch

I am looking for a way to select a region of a PyTorch tensor using a torch function (without using numpy). Do you have suggestions on how to proceed?

In other words, I'm looking for a way to crop a region of a matrix. Using numpy, it would be something like

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.rand(16,16)
B = A[0:8, 0:8]
```

The approach I am trying is the following:

```
from torchvision import transforms
A = torch.randn([1,3,64,64])
B = torch.split(A, [16,32,16], dim =2)
C = torch.split(B, [16,32,16], dim =3)
```

Which gives the error

> 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with regular slicing?

```py
import torch

A = torch.randn([1,3,64,64])
B = A[..., 16:32, 16:32]
```

Comment: For some weird reason I have to avoid that... I ended up using `torch.nn.functional.pad`, like `A = torch.nn.functional.pad(D, (0,-32,0,-32))`.

Comment: @albus_c this is indeed a twisted workaround. If you can explain what prevents you from using regular indices, we might find a better/simpler solution. pytorch is quite flexible (I think as flexible as numpy in this case).